# Jenkins pipeline with GIT LFS settings

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git-lfs

How can i configure a jenkins pipeline build to use git lfs with specific settings.

I have these in my .git/config:

```
[lfs "https://myabc.com/gerrit/proj12345.git/info/lfs"]
    access = basic
    locksverify = false
```

In jenkins pipeline, i cannot find documentation other then having below extension the `[$class: 'GitLFSPull']`.

How can i put the specific options in the pipeline script?